# how to test adding annotations on iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, mapkit

I am developing a simple Map application on the iphone.
I have followed online available tutorials for this.
My question is how do i test it on the iphone simulator?
I can see the map and zoom in and out alright.
I however cant add annotations or "drip the pin" on the simulator.
Any help as in which keys i have to press to simulate that?

Comment: M new to this forum so dint knw much abt it.
Thnx for d tip!!

Answer (score 0):

You can zoom an dezoom like on iPhone: using double tap to zoom and two finger tap to dezoom.

You can also use alt key on simulator to simulate pinch.

**EDIT** : Sorry, misread your question.

You can "Drop a pin" by using clic and hold, it should appears after few secs.

Comment: yeah i am able to do that..pinch zoom in/out
but how do i drop a pin on a location?

Comment: 2 finger tap does not zoom out.. for that we need to press option key which displays 2 finger points on the simulator screen.
That enables to simulate the "pinch" effect

Comment: you can do two finger taps with alt key, without pinching ;)